# How is a half door made in Minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

How can we have the half wooden door in Minecraft? I've tried with the data value ID and nothing's working? Could Notch have removed it from the game?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> After update 1.7_01, doors would make purple particle effects when hit with any tool, hand, item, or block. This was fixed in 1.7.3.
>
> — [Minecraft Wiki - Doors](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Doors)

I believe as part of the door duplication and door bug problems, the lower half bug has been fixed...

> 1.7.3: Corrected a block duplication bug when using pistons.
>
> 1.7.3: Doors no longer create purple particles.
>
> 1.7.1: The door duplication bug is back again, this time happening when a piston pushes on the lower half of a door. If it is a normal piston that does it, then the piston can be destroyed and the bottom half of the door works like a normal door.
>
> — [Minecraft Wiki - Version history](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Version_history)

In 1.7.3, the door duplication bug with Pistons is most likely to have been fixed.

Thus, the ability for the lower half door to be able to exist alone in the world could be gone...

Answer (score 10):

There used to be a bug that resulted in doors being incorrectly destroyed, and leaving half a door remaining. I believe this has been fixed, as per [Tom Wijsman's answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/27813/how-is-a-half-door-made-in-minecraft/27815#27815). However, if you would like to make half-doors, gates etc., consider the [Multi-use Doors Mod](http://www.minecraftforum.net/topic/338754-173v11-multi-use-doors/), which adds this functionality to the game, as well as other door-related happiness and excitement:

[image: Half Door Mod]

Answer (score 7):

What you're looking for is basically [a fence gate.](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Fence_gate) Craft one with two planks vertically stacked and two sticks on each side.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Yeah now it's a fence gate but when the question was asked it was a half door not a fence gate!

Comment: @Warface well now's now! People having this question _now_ don't care about the original timestamp...

Comment: This isn't what he meant. He meant about the door that's 2 blocks high and he wants to know how to get one block of it.

Comment: I don't know if I'm sure, but... This question is too old, no? When Minecraft was in the beta version this question appeared.

Answer (score 2):

***YES YOU CAN!*** Place your door in minecraft then save and exit the game. Go into MC Edit and replace the top half of the door with air, Save and exit. Reload your world and there you go. a working half door.

Just be sure not to place anything where the top half of the door should be, as the door will simply pop off the wall.

Answer (score 2):

You can type `/give [username] 64:1`

Answer (score 0):

There exists (or at least existed until 1.12) a bug involving Dragon Eggs which allowed them to break any block in certain circumstances. This includes the top half of a door.
**What you have to do is to make a Dragon Egg fall in a so-called "lazy chunk".** These lazy chunks are non-entity processing chunks, which can be easily made using a remote chunk loader, that can be created with a long Redstone wire (12+ chunks long, meaning that you also need Repeaters).

Here's how to do it:

1. Place a Sticky Piston at least 4 blocks up in the air, at the end of the long Redstone wire.
2. Link it to the Redstone wire.
3. Extend it by powering the wire.
4. Place a Dragon Egg above the Piston's head.
5. Place a Door on the ground below the Piston's head.
6. Go to the beginning of the Redstone wire, and unpower it.
7. Go back to the door and you can see its top half removed. Unfortunately, any block update will also break the lower half.

*Please note that this method also worked for removing Bedrock, End Portal Frames and such.*